# Automate Power BI Report/Dashboard Deployments

Tags: powershell, deployment, powerbi

I have always done manual report publishing to PBI work-space and it has worked well. Let's me have better control over;

- Publishing
- Dashboarding
- Collaborating
- Securing

I have started a new piece of work and requirements are to have all the above or if not at least publish the reports using automated scripts.

I have googled and I haven't found anything that purely talks about automating using, say Powershell or any other method barring C#.

We have plans to use Powershell scripts to deploy Azure modules and was looking for something similar for PBI as well.

Would appreciate pointers to any script that I can customize and use or a tutorial that explains this process.

Cheers...

Comment: A new module has been published by Microsoft for Power BI management. It was announced at the business analytics summit few weeks ago. [ref](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-apis-and-powershell-cmdlets-for-power-bi-administrators/)

Comment: You can check my powershell script at this post.
[Check here similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57986480/programmatically-deploying-power-bi-reports-to-power-bi-report-server-and-change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the PowerBI service to automate all of this, which is the referred way, recommended by Microsoft, as seen on https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Automation-for-Power-BI-Desktop/td-p/332560, or you can use this python script by dubravcik:  https://github.com/dubravcik/pbixrefresher-python